# Powershell to find all the saved time & saved by for one single file

Tags: powershell

We have couple excel files are used by several departments, and we would like to track on user and saved time. excel can read some info, but not accurate if the file got recovered.

For these files, they can be updated, then got recovered to prior version. There is a need to share all info upon time and user that saved the file in the last month.

Is it achievable by using powershell codes ?

Thank you for your time in advance.

May

Comment: I don't think what you're after will be possible as NTFS doesn't hold all this information. It might be best to look at an external auditing product such as Quest's Change Auditor which can be configured to monitor file systems for changes and record/alert as appropriate.

Comment: If you want to record future saves then yes.But if you are trying to get the past then no its not possible.